# SwitfUI Published on static property

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, viewmodel

I have a View Model defined as such:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var logs: String = ""
}
```

I would like to modify the logs property from the global scope of my Swift code without initializing MyViewModel like so:

```
MyViewModel.logs = "log message\n"
```

I tried making the logs property static:

```
@Published public static var logs: String = ""
```

However I get this error:

> 'wrappedValue' is unavailable: @Published is only available on properties of classes

How do I modify the published property without an instance of MyViewModel?

Comment: Compiler message is pretty clear here, just nothing to add.

Comment: In that case, how do I modify the published property from a global scope without using an instance of MyViewModel?

Comment: EnvironmentObject?

Answer (score 4):

you could try using a singleton pattern, such as

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var logs: String = ""
    
    public static let shared = MyViewModel()  // <--- here
}
```

then

```
MyViewModel.shared.logs = "log message\n"
```